# KeyRelease в eventFilter

Tags: c++, qt

в моем приложении есть основной класс, наследуемый от QObject, в нем метод eventFilter. Мне нужно отлавливать событие отпускания клавиши, но я заметил, что если зажать кнопку, то KeyRelease генерируется автоматически через секунду. Если бы был метод keyRelease (который есть в классах, наследуемых от QWidget), я бы просто использовал метод isAutoRepeat(), чтобы отключить обработку автоматически сгенерированных событий, но здесь такого нет, есть ли способ отключить эту автоматическую генерацию keyRelease (поменять наследование класс c QObject на QWidget никак нельзя)

```html
bool Counter::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = (QKeyEvent *)event;

        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Space) {
          return true;
        }
    }

    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = (QKeyEvent *)event;

        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Space) {
          return true;
        }
    }
  return Counter::eventFilter(target, event);
}
```

Comment: А платформа какая? Если виндоуз, то можно напрямую винапишные функции попробовать, типа [GetAsyncKeyState](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Вообще кроссплатформенное приложение, а какие функции к примеру, я не силен в этом?

Comment: Кстати офтоп, но сишное приведение здесь не безопасно, тут `dynamic_cast` нужен по-хорошему.

Comment: Это просто пример, он не из проекта

Comment: И почему нельзя использовать `isAutoRepeat()`?

Comment: у QObject нет такого метота, он есть у QKeyEvent

Comment: Так я про это и спрашиваю, что мешает?

Comment: Если вы о том чтобы поменять наследование с QObject на QWidget, то это не вариант, проект очень большой, а это по сути основной его класс

Comment: Нет, я о том чтобы вызывать `keyEvent->isAutoRepeat()`

Comment: в данном eventFilter у нас обычный QEvent, в нем этого метода нет, вы говорите о методе void keyRelease(QKeyEvent *keyEvent), в нем можно такое провернуть, но этот метод работает только в классах, которые наследуются от QWidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию `QKeyEvent::isAutoRepeat()`, которая возвращает `истина` если событие появилось в результате автоповторения, что и есть ваш случай. В общем, как-то так должно быть:

```
bool Counter::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
   if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
   {
       QKeyEvent * key_event = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);

       if (     key_event 
            &&  key_event->key() == Qt::Key_Space
            && !key_event->isAutoRepeat() ) 
       {
           //return true; 
           // здесь возвращать true не совсем корректно
           // так как тогда эти события не получит целевой виджет
       }
   }

   if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
   {
       QKeyEvent * key_event = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);

       if (     key_event 
            &&  key_event->key() == Qt::Key_Space
            && !key_event->isAutoRepeat() ) 
       {
          //return true;
       }
   }
   return Counter::eventFilter(target, event);
}
```

Comment: Блин, у меня походу каша образовалась, спасибо

Comment: Cerdo, такая проблема нарисовалась, что где-то после некоторого кол-ва нажатий, приложение падает, конкретно в строке создания

Comment: QKeyEvent * key_event = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event); причем event не пустой, но поля его занулены

Comment: Забавно что если использовать static_cast, то все работает

Comment: @Mike1995 Маловероятно такое, вы где-то ошибаетесь